# Socket.IO messaging to multiple rooms

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using Socket.IO in my Node Express app, and using the methods described in [this excellent post](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress/) to relate my socket connections and sessions.  In [a comment](http://www.danielbaulig.de/socket-ioexpress#div-comment-1158) the author describes a way to send messages to a particular user (session) like this:

```
sio.on('connection', function (socket) {
    // do all the session stuff
    socket.join(socket.handshake.sessionID);
    // socket.io will leave the room upon disconnect
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    sio.sockets.in(req.sessionID).send('Man, good to see you back!');
});
```

Seems like a good idea.  However, in my app I will often by sending messages to multiple users at once.  I'm wondering about the best way to do this in Socket.IO - essentially I need to send messages to multiple rooms with the best performance possible.  Any suggestions?

Comment: have you found a good way to do it (send the same message to different users in a group/room chat). ?

Answer (score 8):

Two options: use socket.io channels or socket.io namespaces. Both are documented on the socket.io website, but in short:

Using channels:

```
// all on the server
// on connect or message received
socket.join("channel-name");
socket.broadcast.to("channel-name").emit("message to all other users in channel");

// OR independently
io.sockets.in("channel-name").emit("message to all users in channel");
```

Using namespaces:

```
// on the client connect to namespace
io.connect("/chat/channel-name")

// on the server receive connections to namespace as normal
// broadcast to namespace
io.of("/chat/channel-name").emit("message to all users in namespace")
```

Because socket.io is smart enough to not actually open a second socket for additional namespaces, both methods should be comparable in efficiency.

Comment: I think these are equivalent to what I'm already doing to identify each user.  That is, each user gets his own socket.io channel based on his session key, and I broadcast to that channel in order to send to that user (instead of just emitting on one socket directly).  So my question is: if two of these users (each represented by a room) need to receive the same message, is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: shouldn't the last bit be `io.of('/chat/channel-name')